# Custom listview is too slow

Tags: android, performance, listview, adapter, android-custom-view

Well my custom listview is very very slow, almost unusable, I have been reading a lot of post but no one help me to fix it, I hope one of you can, thanks.

Here is my item listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300px"
        android:id="@id/iv_tipo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="27px"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:id="@id/tv_titulo"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:paddingBottom="20px"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the adapter

```
public class TrucoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<Truco> trucos;

    public TrucoListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Truco> trucos) {
        super(context, 0, trucos);
        trucos = this.trucos;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(super.getCount() - position - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.truco_list_item, null);

        }


        ImageView ivTipo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tipo);
        TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);

        Truco truco = (Truco)getItem(position);

        switch (truco.getTipo()) {
            case "m":
                ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.coins);
                break;
            case "c":
                ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cards);
                break;
            case "a":
                ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.guess);
                break;
            case "d":
                ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.desa);
                break;
            default:
                ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);

        }

            tvTitulo.setText(truco.getTitulo());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

EDIT: I modified my adapter as @KishanSoni suggested me, but it is still slow.

Comment: That's because you aren't using the **`ViewHolder pattern`**

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for the fast answer, i tried once but did not solve the trouble

Comment: first of all use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Load images using Image caching libraries like `Picasso or UIL or Glide`..that is the only reason for your laggy listview..

Answer (score 0):

Use Base Adapter instead of Array Adapter
Also use Holder Pattern,
For Example i am Giving you Sample of it

```
public class MyAdpt extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ArrayList<String> mdata;

    public MyAdpt (ArrayList<String> data) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mdata = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mdata.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mdata.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ItemViewHolder itemHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            itemHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            itemHolder.textview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        } else {
            itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        itemHolder.textview.setText(mdata.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder {
        TextView textview;
    }
}
```

Edit :

```
public class TrucoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Truco> trucos;

public TrucoListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Truco> trucos) {
    super(context, 0, trucos);
    trucos = this.trucos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return trucos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return trucos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ItemViewHolder itemHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        itemHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.truco_list_item, null);

        itemHolder.ImageView ivTipo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_tipo);
        itemHolder.TextView tvTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
        convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
    } else {
        itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Truco truco = (Truco) getItem(position);

    switch (truco.getTipo()) {
    case "m":
        ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.coins);
        break;
    case "c":
        ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cards);
        break;
    case "a":
        ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.guess);
        break;
    case "d":
        ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.desa);
        break;
    default:
        ivTipo.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);

    return convertView;
}

public class ItemViewHolder {
    ImageView ivTipo;
    TextView tvTitulo;
}
}
```

Comment: I did it exactly as you, and its still very slow /: @KishanSoni

Answer (score 0):

Some questions-

The Truco class: getTito() and getTitulo()- do they do any expensive processing?

Are the drawables small (icon size)? IE, are you processing 200K drawables?

How many trucos are you loading into the arraylist?

Sorry, I can't add this as a comment due to low rep.